# Mobile Safari not resizing Unicode pictographs

Tags: html, unicode

Look at the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    body.c1 {font-size:66pt}
    /*]]>*/
    </style>
    </head>
    <body id="body" class="ignoreWebkitDefault c1">
    A &#128276;
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I run this in Safari on my MacBook, both the character and the pictograph get resized. On my iPad, only the character gets resized. Any workaround?

[image: iPad 6.0 Simulator]

[image: safari]

Comment: the syntax doesnt matter in this case. i have changed it nevertheless. look at the two screenshots

Comment: Nope! I assume it is a bug with Mobile Safari. If you get any closer to the answer, lemme know